# UNUSED() with teeth in C++11 debug builds

Tags: c++, c++11

When you turn up the compiler warnings with `-Wunused-variable`, one tends to then employ [an `UNUSED()` macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030983/211160), to say something is intentionally not used at this time.

But that's not very binding, since it's generally just a void cast (or near-equivalent).  Hence if you get the warning, add an UNUSED(), and some time later actually do use the variable...it's misleading to to the reader of the code.

I got the odd idea of making C++11 give this some level of "enforcement", by seeing if it got in a POD lvalue it could trash it.  Obviously won't work for everything (unused constants, etc.)  But I kind of fiddled with it until it had the effect I wanted--while I can't say exactly why every variation I tried didn't work.

You could break it out in various ways to do something special for `std::is_pointer<>` or other types, or even have some kind of "trashme()" method detection for non-POD values.  But here's the core of the idea:

```
#if !defined(NDEBUG)

template<
    typename T,
    typename TRR = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_lvalue_reference<T &&>::value
        || std::is_const<TRR>::value
        || !std::is_pod<TRR>::value
    >::type* = nullptr
>
void UNUSED(T && v) {
    static_cast<void>(v);
}

template<
    typename T,
    typename TRR = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T &&>::value
        && !std::is_const<TRR>::value
        && std::is_pod<TRR>::value
    >::type* = nullptr
>
void UNUSED(T && v) {
    memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof(TRR)); // or 0xDECAFBAD pattern, etc.
}

#endif
```

Anything cleaner/simpler to achieve the same effect, or ideas to make it better?

Comment: Are you searching for [this attribute](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0212r1.pdf)?

Comment: @Incomputable Interesting to know that exists, and that someone was specific enough about the semantics to add "maybe" onto it.  (If you can't solve the problem, point out that you can't...!)  But the trick here is I'm actually using C++11 to instrument a codebase that is committed to using only C, so the conventional UNUSED() is what it has to be working with.

Answer (score 4):

#### Missing headers

This code needs

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
```

#### Use `sizeof` operator on a value

While we can write `sizeof (type)`, in this case we have a value, and we can use it here - [`sizeof` will read through the reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/26631169), saving us some work:

```
std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
```

#### Reduce repetition

There are two expressions that need to be maintained in parallel in the `std::enable_if` template.  We can refactor these into a single trait template:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_mutable_pod_lvalue
    : std::integral_constant<bool,
                             std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value
                             && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
                             && std::is_pod<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value>
{};
```

Then the functions reduce to

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value>::type
UNUSED(T && v) {
    static_cast<void>(v);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value>::type
UNUSED(T && v) {
    std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
}
```

In C++14, we could use the `_t` and `_v` forms to avoid typing `::type` and `::value` respectively, and in C++17, we could use `std::bool_constant` instead of `std::integral_constant`.

If we were using C++17, we could further reduce to a single function, by moving the test within the function body:

```
template<typename T>
UNUSED(T&& v) {
    if constexpr (is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value)
        std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
}
```

Now we're no longer using `is_mutable_pod_value` more than once, we can just inline it back again:

```
template<typename T>
void UNUSED(T&& v) {
    static const bool is_mutable_pod_lvalue =
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value
        && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
        && std::is_pod<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;

    if constexpr ((is_mutable_pod_lvalue)
        std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
}
```

#### Enhancement: accept multiple arguments

Here's a varargs template that makes it easier to use:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
void UNUSED(T&& v, U&&... u)
{
    UNUSED(v);
    UNUSED(u...);
}
```

Again, C++17 makes this simpler, with fold expressions:

```
template<typename... T>
void UNUSED(T&&... v)
{
    (UNUSED(v) , ...);
}
```

#### A definition is required when `NDEBUG` is set

Probably just an oversight, but the code is missing an `#else` block.  It's probably worth reordering so that the positive branch comes first (confusing because `NDEBUG` is itself a negative...).  Further, since the only difference between the debug and non-debug cases it the use of `std::memset()` in one of the implementations, we can reduce the scope of `#ifdef` to just that (at a small cost to non-debug compilation times):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value>::type
UNUSED(T&& v)
{
    static_cast<void>(v);
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
#endif
}
```

## Revised code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
template<typename T>
struct is_mutable_pod_lvalue
    : std::integral_constant<bool,
                             std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value
                             && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
                             && std::is_pod<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value>
{};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value>::type
UNUSED(T&& v)
{
    static_cast<void>(v);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_mutable_pod_lvalue<T>::value>::type
UNUSED(T&& v)
{
    static_cast<void>(v);
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::memset(&v, 0xBD, sizeof v);
#endif
}

template<typename T, typename... U>
void UNUSED(T&& v, U&&... u)
{
    UNUSED(v);
    UNUSED(u...);
}
```

```
#include <memory>
void f(int i, const int ci, int& ri, const int& cri, int *pi,
       std::unique_ptr<int> ui, std::unique_ptr<int>&& rrui)
{
#ifdef TEST_UNUSED
    UNUSED(i, ci, ri, cri, pi, ui, rrui);
#endif
}
```

Four compilations are required to test this fully for all combinations of `TEST_UNUSED` and `NDEBUG`.

Comment: May be you could bring the curly braces down? The absence of curly braces make me feel like the definition is not done yet. Though that may be the problem with the post width, on my screen it would probably be much higher.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you mean (I thought by "bring down" that you meant "reduce the number of").  I see now that you just wanted the template's definition `{}` on a new line, which makes sense - now done.

Comment: Possible enhancement - for a non-POD mutable value, could we placement-delete, and then overwrite the storage?  We'd need a way to reinstate it to a valid state before it goes out of scope and meets its destructor...

Comment: Perhaps `UNUSED<T>` could be a non-copyable class containing a `T` and a `T&`, which would then move-construct the value into its own storage when constructed, and move it back in the destructor?

Comment: that sounds interesting. Though will increase constraints on type. Is runtime cost of any value in the macro?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Nice idea with the multiple args, though I can't use that in a C codebase.  Runtime cost is a factor for me, so no need to try anything fancier unless you find it entertaining...